# Как работать с вложенными данными в сессию Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

как в Symfony можно добавить несколько вложенных элементов
например в чистом php можно писать так

```
$_SESSION['cart'][23] = [
   'id'    => 23,
   'name'  => 'Продукт 1',
   'price' => 240,
   'qty'   => 1,
];
```

Как тоже самое можно делать в Symfony?

```
$session->set(23, [
   'id'    => $id,
   'qty'   => $qty,
   'price' => $order->getPrice(),
]);
```

Если использовать такой код, то я не могу не получается добавить название cart.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#namespaced-attributes

Comment: Этот вариант не подходит.

Comment: А другого и нет.